# Probability of Hardy-Weinberg principle

Tags: probability

I'm a bit confused on how to optimize the HW equation.

The equation is defined as, given two alleles, $A$ and $a$, and $frequency(A) = p$ and $frequency(a) = q$. Now, we have $p+q = 1 = p^2 + 2pq + q^2$.

Let's say I have P(AA), P(Aa), and P(aa) and I want to know the maximum probability of getting P(Aa). What does this even mean?

The only method I can think of is drawing a parabola and finding the endpoint of a rectangle fully self contained inside this curve as it would denote the biggest value for A*a. But I feel like this is completely off from what I should do.

Should I be looking for a relationship between $A$ and $a$?

Comment: I think that including the Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium formula in your question could be helpful to those who aren't familiar with it.

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(Aa)$ is given by $2pq$ in Hardy-Weinberg.

Since $p^2+2pq+q^2=1$, the maximum value of $2pq$ is $0.5$.

You can easily verify this by checking the extremes. If you plug in $p=.99$ and $q=.01$, you get a $2pq$ value of $.0198$. Conversely, If you plug in $p-.49$ and $q=.51$, $2pq=.4998$ which is less than the value we get when the frequencies of $A$ and $a$ are equal.

In response to what does this mean, this represents the maximum proportion of a population in H-W equilibrium that can be heterozygous. This makes sense because of the parameters that must be met for H-W to hold. I hope this helps.

Comment: I see, the maximum value makes perfect sense, but is there a more methodical way to arrive at this number than by plugging in extremes?

Comment: The reason I ask is, if I had more than just $p$ and $q$, then I want to be able to generalize.

Comment: Think of maximizing area of a rectangle just in this case, the sides are $p$ and $q$. That is, area is maximized when all sides are equal to each other. The same intuition can be extended to other forms, the area of a triangle is maximized when it is an equilateral.